# Riverpod state management - update UI, when request gets called

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-state

I have a `MainPage`, where I have a `ListView` of my rooms. The ListView uses the response from my `getUserRooms` service. Everything works fine; I can't understand why The `ListView` doesn't update when my `createRoom` request gets called, which is in the same service as the `getUserRooms` functionality. I'm managing the state using Riverpod

Here are my HTTP requests:

```
class RoomService {
  RoomRoutes roomRoutes = RoomRoutes();

  final _preferencesService = SharedPreferences();

  Future<List> createRoom(RoomModelRequest postBody) async {
    if (postBody.roomPassword!.trim().isEmpty) {
      postBody.roomPassword = null;
    }

    if (postBody.roomName!.trim().isEmpty) {
      postBody.roomName = null;
    }

    try {
      final userData = await _preferencesService.getPreferences();

      final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(roomRoutes.roomsURL),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            'Authorization': 'Token ${userData.token}'
          },
          body: jsonEncode(postBody.toJson()));

      switch (response.statusCode) {
        case 201:
          final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
          return [response.statusCode, data["Success"]];

        
        default:
          throw Exception(response.reasonPhrase);
      }
    } on SocketException {
      throw Exception("No internet connection");
    } on TimeoutException catch (e) {
      throw Exception("Connection timeout: ${e.message} ");
    } on Exception {
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  Future<List<RoomModelResponse>> getUserRooms() async {
    try {
      final userData = await _preferencesService.getPreferences();

      final response =
          await http.get(Uri.parse(roomRoutes.extendedRoomsURL), headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Authorization': 'Token ${userData.token}'
      });

      switch (response.statusCode) {
        case 200:
          Iterable json = jsonDecode(response.body);
          return json.map((room) => RoomModelResponse.fromJson(room)).toList();

       
        default:
          throw Exception(response.reasonPhrase);
      }
    } on SocketException {
      throw Exception("No internet connection");
    } on TimeoutException catch (e) {
      throw Exception("Connection timeout: ${e.message} ");
    } on Exception {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}
```

Here in the same file, I have my room provider:

```
final roomProvider = Provider<RoomService>((ref) => RoomService());
```

And I'm watching the state of that provider, where on update the getUserRooms is returned.

```
final roomDataProvider = FutureProvider<List<RoomModelResponse>>((ref) async {
  return ref.watch(roomProvider).getUserRooms();
});
```

In my `MainPage` that is how I get the response data

```
class MainPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MainPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ref) {
    // provider
    final data = ref.watch(roomDataProvider);

    final roomIDController = TextEditingController();
    final uniqueIDRoom = TextEditingController();

    // UI screen size
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    double deviceWidth = size.width;
    double deviceHeight = size.height;

    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: bluePrimary,
        body: data.when(
            data: (data) {
              List<RoomModelResponse> roomList =
                  data.map((room) => room).toList();
              return SafeArea(
                  child: Container(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 36, vertical: 16),
                child: Column(
                    //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          IconButton(
                            iconSize: deviceWidth * 0.09,
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.person_outline,
                                color: orangePrimary),
                            onPressed: () {},
                          ),
                          IconButton(
                            icon: const Icon(
                              Icons.add,
                              color: orangePrimary,
                            ),
                            iconSize: deviceWidth * 0.09,
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) =>
                                        const CreateRoomScreen()),
                              );
                            },
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: deviceHeight * 0.04),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: Text("W",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Chalet',
                                fontSize: deviceWidth * 0.12,
                                color: orangePrimary,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                height: deviceHeight * 0.001)),
                      ),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: Text("W",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Chalet',
                                fontSize: deviceWidth * 0.12,
                                color: whitePrimary,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                height: deviceHeight * 0.001)),
                      ),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: Text("M",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Chalet',
                                fontSize: deviceWidth * 0.12,
                                color: orangePrimary,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                height: deviceHeight * 0.001)),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: deviceHeight * 0.04),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: Text("Join room",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Chalet',
                                fontSize: deviceWidth * 0.07,
                                color: whitePrimary,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
                                height: deviceHeight * 0.001)),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: deviceHeight * 0.008),

                      // email textField
                      SizedBox(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.85,
                        child: TextField(
                          controller: roomIDController,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              filled: true,
                              fillColor: whitePrimary,
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                                  borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                              hintText: 'Enter room ID to join it',
                              hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 174, 173, 173))),
                        ),
                      ),

                      SizedBox(height: deviceHeight * 0.016),

                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                        child: FloatingActionButton(
                          backgroundColor: orangePrimary,
                          child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios_rounded,
                              color: whitePrimary),
                          onPressed: () {},
                        ),
                      ),

                      SizedBox(height: deviceHeight * 0.020),

                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: Text("My rooms",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Chalet',
                                fontSize: deviceWidth * 0.07,
                                color: whitePrimary,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
                                height: deviceHeight * 0.001)),
                      ),

                      SizedBox(height: deviceHeight * 0.014),

                      // Display horizontal scroll rooms
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: SizedBox(
                          width: deviceWidth,
                          child: SizedBox(
                            height: deviceWidth * 0.56,
                            width: deviceWidth * 0.42,
                            child: ListView.builder(
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              itemCount: roomList.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return Stack(children: [
                                  Container(
                                    height: deviceWidth * 0.8,
                                    width: deviceWidth * 0.42,
                                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        horizontal: 3),
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                  ),
                                  InkWell(
                                    child: Container(
                                      height: deviceWidth * 0.4,
                                      width: deviceWidth * 0.42,
                                      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                          horizontal: 3),
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: orangePrimary,
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                          boxShadow: const [
                                            BoxShadow(
                                                color: Colors.black,
                                                offset: Offset(0, 5),
                                                blurRadius: 10)
                                          ]),
                                      child: Image.asset(
                                          "assets/Logo.png"),
                                    ),
                                    onTap: () {},
                                  ),
                                  Positioned(
                                      bottom: 35,
                                      left: 12,
                                      child: Text(roomList[index].roomName)),
                                  Positioned(
                                      bottom: 15,
                                      left: 12,
                                      child: GestureDetector(
                                        onTap: () {
                                          uniqueIDRoom.text =
                                              roomList[index].uniqueID;
                                          Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(
                                              text: uniqueIDRoom.text));

                                          const snackBar = SnackBar(
                                            content: Text("Copied room ID"),
                                          );

                                          // Find the ScaffoldMessenger in the widget tree
                                          // and use it to show a SnackBar.
                                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                              .showSnackBar(snackBar);
                                        },
                                        child: Text(
                                            "ID: ${roomList[index].uniqueID}",
                                            style: const TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                      ))
                                ]);
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ]),
              ));
            },
            error: (err, s) => Text(err.toString()),
            loading: () => const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                )));
  }
}
```

Then, to create the room, I navigate the user to another screen perform a HTTP request, which, if successful returns the user to the MainPage again, and I expect the rooms to be updated, including the new room, also.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the complete `MainPage`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *RoomService* and *roomDataProvider* are not implemented to notify changes to listeners of those providers. You shall modify you code such that depending on you case they extend a `Notifier` class, in your case it should be `AsyncNotifier`.

**Key concepts**: A `Provider` is just an utility that (as its name indicates) provides, across your entire app, a certain `type` of object. That object is cached and hence the same object is returned. A `Notifier` is a special type of `Provider` which has an internal **state** property which stores the object to be returned. This *state* can be updated by implementing [methods](https://riverpod.dev/es/docs/essentials/side_effects#exposing-a-method-to-perform-a-post-request) which assign new instances to the *state* property. Listeners to that `NotifierProvider` will be notified of any updates on that state (this is done by invoking the `watch` method in your code wherever you need that state object).

It is key that you identify and clearly define what the *state* returned by your provider is, and implement your code accordingly (maybe in your case it is a list of rooms??)

Then when that *state* is modified, for example when getting new data when performing a `get` HTTP request, you shall assign that new data object to the `state` variable of the Riverpod notifier, which will notify any `Consumer` widgets which are "watching".

Your use case is almost exactly what the official Riverpod documentation explains in its example for To-do lists. You should [take a look at it](https://riverpod.dev/es/docs/essentials/side_effects).

Comment: First, thanks for answering.. After making the RoomService extend AsyncNotifier, it tells me that 'AsyncNotifier.build' should be implemented. Even after reading the link you provided me, I'm not sure, that I fully get what should end up in that AsyncNotifier.build, taking my code as example

Comment: I have updated my answer to provide more info. Method `build` is just equivalent to an initialization, it constructs the object which is initially returned by the provider (the initial object stored in the *state* of the `Notifier`). In your case it could be an empty list, or maybe it could perform an initial HTTP get (I would recommend using [dio library](https://pub.dev/packages/dio)) and return an initial list of Rooms.

Answer (score -2):

1. Ensure that the state is being updated:

   ref.read(roomDataProvider.notifier).refresh();
2. Use `StateNotifierProvider` instead of `FutureProvider` for better control:

   final roomStateProvider = StateNotifierProvider<RoomNotifier, List>((ref) {
   return RoomNotifier(ref.read);
   });

   ```
       class RoomNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<RoomModelResponse>> {
         final Reader read;

         RoomNotifier(this.read) : super([]);

         Future<void> refresh() async {
           final rooms = await read(roomProvider).getUserRooms();
           state = rooms;
         }
       }
   ```
3. Use `Consumer` widget to watch for changes:

   Consumer(
   builder: (context, ref, child) {
   final rooms = ref.watch(roomStateProvider);
   // Build UI using rooms
   },
   )
4. Check if the `roomDataProvider` is being called on screen re-entry:

   // In your MainPage build method
   final data = ref.watch(roomDataProvider);
   if (data.isEmpty) {
   // Fetch data again or trigger a refresh
   ref.refresh(roomDataProvider);
   }

Comment: where do you ensure that the state is being updated? "1. Ensure that the state is being updated:

ref.read(roomDataProvider.notifier).refresh();"

Comment: I'm kinda new, but is step 4 the right way to do that, wont that cause a non stop fetching data? Or at least it is how it sounds to me

Comment: After successfully creating a room, make sure you update the state. You can use ref.refresh(roomDataProvider) or another mechanism to trigger a rebuild of the UI.

Comment: Avoid legacy riverpod tools. In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).